# Config File Help Too Many Values Needed

Tags: python

I have a python script which uses settings.cfg which looks like:

```
[site1]
url=http://boots4tall.com,http://myboots.com,http://boots.com,http://xbox.com,http://xboxOne.com
category=Boots,Boots,Boots,Xbox,Xbox
```

And the python script function:

```
def main():
    config=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.readfp(open("settings.cfg"),"r")
    for site in config.sections():
       # ipdb.set_trace()
        settings=dict(config.items(site))
        for (url,category) in zip(settings['url'].split(","),settings['category'].split(",")):
```

My main goal is to use specific url for specific category. Most of the times it's 1-4 different url's for 1 category. So I pick 1 category 1 url and let the script do anything related to this url + category.

My problem: I have 1200 categories and around 3000 urls. It will be very hard for me to manually add those categories + urls without mistake in 1 line which is really hard. So I ask for your help can you help get a better system? I thought about reading lines from text files for example 1 file urls.txt 1 file categories.txt? How the code should even look for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing your configuration as [json](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html). In my opinion, it is far easier to create, load, and read than config files.

You can create a JSON config file like this:

```
[{'category': 'Boots', 'url': 'http://boots4tall.com'},
 {'category': 'Boots', 'url': 'http://myboots.com'},
 {'category': 'Boots', 'url': 'http://boots.com'},
 {'category': 'Xbox', 'url': 'http://xbox.com'},
 {'category': 'Xbox', 'url': 'http://xboxOne.com'}
 ...
]
```

When you load the config file, you can then iterate over each category/url pair:

```
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    pairs = json.load(f)

for item in pairs:
    category = item['category']
    url = item['url']
    # process them here...
```

If you have a list of categories and URLs in Python, then it is easy to initially generate such a config file:

```
import json

pairs = [{'url': url, 'category': category} for (url, category) in zip(urls, categories))]
with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(pairs, f)
```

Comment: The script runs in crontab and when it runs it should run through all the urls + categories. I think it will be very hard to create for each category and url JSON config file. The easiest way I see is new line in text file

Comment: If you already have a Python list of those categories and URLs, it's not too difficult to serialize them to JSON. I'll add an example.

Comment: I don't have a list now it looks like it can be good choice is there a convertor from text file to JSON? I can arrange the urls and categories to text file maybe and then convert to JSON if possible

Comment: also do you mind show me the json equivalent of for function? Basically changing my function of config to json

Comment: Sure. I just added an example of loading and iterating over the file.

Comment: Thank you nofinator! If only you could solve the last problem I will arrange all categories to categories.txt and all urls to urls.txt is there a way to combine them into a 1 JSON line?

Answer (score 2):

Given how many categories and urls you use / require, I would use an SQLite database to store the categories and URLs and retrieve them when needed. Yes, it adds a bit of overhead and more code but it's easier to maintain and update.

Comment: The script runs in crontab and when it runs it should run through all the urls + categories. Will it be simple to implement? I have to do add urls + categories manually

Comment: Yes it should, as long as user permissions are correct you shouldn't have problems. The complex part would be coding the SQLite access but since good documentation is abundant it's a trivial process.

You can even update the SQLite database (it's actually a single file) live without stopping the cron and it should work just as well.